# Creating an event using Events Manager and JSON API

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-json-api

I'm creating an app using the JSON API plugin in conjunction with this Events Manager Plugin in WordPress and I want to create an event using the `create_post` controller.

For example:

```
url:'http://yoursite.com/api/posts/create_post/?nonce=' + eventNonce + '&type=event&title=' + eventTitle,
```

That's enough to get the event created as a draft, but I'm not allowed to publish it until I have the location and the date info in the proper format.

I found that adding `&location=` or `&date=` doesn't work.

I even tried the custom parameters (`&custom[_event_end_date]=`) referenced in a previous [support question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-events-with-api-rest?replies=1), but none of that works for me.

Comment: `location` and `date` are probably going to be meta data to the post object.  Depending on the situation, it might be easier to POST instead of GET so you can feed it a JSON object instead of a messy string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I am using the POST method. I don't understand what you mean by "feed it a JSON object instead of a mess string." 

How would I go about doing that?